# Сохранение отчета в pdf-файл

Tags: ravereport, pdf, delphi

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема с сохранением отчета RaveReport в файл pdf. Дело в том, что в сгенерированном pdf-файле текст отображается в какой-то непонятной кодировке (иероглифы). Хотя предпросмотр или печать отчета работают хорошо и текст выглядит так, как надо. В чем здесь проблема?

Я уже все шрифты перебрал и в реестре покопался, для примера:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
"1250"="c_1251.nls"
"1251"="c_1251.nls"
"1252"="c_1251.nls"
```

Но толку нет... Файл создается так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
rvProject1.Engine:=RvSystem1;
with RvSystem1 do
       begin
          DoNativeOutput:= False;
          RenderObject:= RvRenderPDF1;
          OutputFileName:= 'myreport.pdf';
       end;
rvProject1.Execute;
end;
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы так и не победили кодировку в Rave Reports для PDF?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте при проектировании отчета в RaveDesigner в свойстве Font задать какой-либо кириллический шрифт. Если в первый раз не получится, попробуйте следующий. Какой-либо из них обязательно сработает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще попробовать поиграться с Font.Charset := RUSSIAN_CHARSET